# Why I'm getting an error informing that "a result was not expected" when executing stored procedures on PostgreSQL from Java in a batch?

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have this procedure in the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replacePageRelevance(id INT, value REAL) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO pageRelevance VALUES (id,value);
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    UPDATE pageRelevance SET relevance = value WHERE pageId = id;       
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And this code that calls this function:

```
private final String PAGE_RELEVANCE_SQL = "SELECT replacePageRelevance(?,?::REAL)";
try (CallableStatement cstm = conn.prepareCall(PAGE_RELEVANCE_SQL)) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : weightMap.entrySet()) {
            cstm.setInt(1, entry.getKey());
            cstm.setDouble(2, entry.getValue());
            cstm.addBatch();
        }
        cstm.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error discovering pages relevance: " + e.getNextException());
    }
}
```

When I execute the batch, the values are inserted or replaced in the table, but after that, I'm getting an exception informing that *`A result was returned when none was expected.`*

I don't know what is wrong, if the way I call the procedure or the procedure itself. What can be the problem and how to solve it?

Call a procedure with `SELECT` is the right/only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell you are using `SELECT` when `call` should be used.

An example from the [PostgreSQL documentation on the JDBC interface](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-callproc.html):

```
// Turn transactions off.
con.setAutoCommit(false);
// Procedure call.
CallableStatement upperProc = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call upper( ? ) }");
upperProc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
upperProc.setString(2, "lowercase to uppercase");
upperProc.execute();
String upperCased = upperProc.getString(1);
upperProc.close();
```

Note that the `? = call` syntax for the result is unnecessary in your case - you will want to use just `call replacePageRelevance(?,?::REAL)`

The reason that this syntax differs from actual PostgreSQL is because this is part of the [JDBC specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

Comment: @Renato - Have you tried?  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-callproc.html (couldn't find docs for 9.0)

Comment: I tried only with a CALL in place of the SELECT. I'm trying with this example, but my function returns VOID.

Comment: Thank you for your help, worked with the {call}. I only want to highlight that `call` must be in lowercase.

Comment: @Renato - ah, didn't realize that, my mistake. Answer edited and +1 now that I learned something too.